# Publishing a Tarball to NPM Missing Cache

Tags: laravel, npm, npm-publish, php-8.2

I have am building a **new** NPM package to be published. In doing so am generating files that will be included via PHP. These are added to a tarball as in the following snippet.

```php
$disk = 'local';
$path = '/';
$tarball = new \PharData('scope-package-1.2.3.tar', format: \Phar::TAR);

foreach(Storage::disk($disk)->allFiles($path) as $file) {
  $tarball->addFromString(basename($file), Storage::disk($disk)->get($file));
}

$tarball->compress(\Phar::GZ, '.tgz');
```

The resulting file, `scope-package-1.2.3.tgz`, looks valid. If I were to `npm publish /path/to/scope-package-1.2.3.tgz` I get the following error.

```bash
npm ERR! code ENOENT\n
npm ERR! syscall open\n
npm ERR! path ~/.npm/_cacache/tmp/rZtgL9/package.json\n
npm ERR! errno -2\n
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '~/.npm/_cacache/tmp/rZtgL9/package.json'\n
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.\n
npm ERR! enoent \n
```

I can't tell where NPM decide the `rZtgL9` portion of that cache.

If I remove the gzipped tarball and in the same directory run `npm pack` this creates a file named the same, and from what I can tell otherwise the same. Both extract correctly on OSX and both have the same contents. If I publish this tarball in the same way, however, it works!

What is it that `npm pack` may be doing that allows it to be fetched from the cache that my code does not? Running `npm pack` does not appear to affect the cache.